# Linq expression resquested

Tags: linq

Let's say I have List of object containing these two records :

EmployeeId - Category - Amount

1 - T - 150

1 - D - 300

The result I want in the final is something looking lie this :

EmployeeId - TAmount - DAmount

1 - 150 - 300

How can I achive this using LINQ, I just don't see how to do this with a simple group by on my EmployeeId field ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var employeeId = 1;
var query =
    from row in table
    group row by row.EmployeeId into g
    where g.Key == employeeId
    select new
    {
        EmployeeId = row.Key,
        TAmount = g.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Categpry == "T"),
        DAmount = g.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Categpry == "D"),
    };
```